# Opengl sdl2 incorrect rendering background texture's and 3d cube's color

Tags: c++, opengl, background, 3d, sdl

I can load and render texture but there is a problem when I try to draw not only a texture but also a cube.
When I don't set cube's one (or more) side's color then it is white and background is fine.
When I set cube's one(or more) side's color by typing:

```
glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
```

everything what is rendered changes it's color to this one.
I was looking for a mistake but I just couldn't find it.

main.cpp

```
 /*This source code copyrighted by Lazy Foo' Productions (2004-2015)
and may not be redistributed without written permission.*/

//Using SDL, SDL OpenGL, standard IO, and, strings
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_opengl.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>
#include <GL\GLU.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include "TesterClass_Cubic.h"

//Screen dimension constants
const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 1366;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 768;

//Starts up SDL, creates window, and initializes OpenGL
bool init();

//Initializes matrices and clear color
bool initGL();

//Input handler
void handleKeys(unsigned char key, int x, int y);

//Per frame update
void update();

//Renders quad to the screen
void render();

//Frees media and shuts down SDL
void close();

//The window we'll be rendering to
SDL_Window* gWindow = NULL;

//OpenGL context
SDL_GLContext gContext;

//Render flag
bool gRenderQuad = true;


GLuint tlo;
TesterClass_Cubic kostka(0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
TesterClass_Cubic kostka_2(0.5, 0, 0, 0);

//BYĆ OSTROŻNYM Z UŻYCIEM, PONIEWAŻ ZAWSZE MUSI MIEĆ AKTUALNĄ WARTOŚĆ
//w innym wypadku funkcja resize może być wywołana dla nieakutalnych wymiarów okna
//zawsze jest updatowana w przypadku: zmiany rozmiaru okna(w funkcji resize)
int current_window_width = SCREEN_WIDTH;
int current_window_height = SCREEN_HEIGHT;

bool perspective_checker = true; // służy do przełączania perspektywy(pozycji kamery, funkcji gllookat), true-widok startowy zza bohatera, false- widok z gory

bool init()
{
    //Initialization flag
    bool success = true;

    //Initialize SDL
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0)
    {
        printf("SDL could not initialize! SDL Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        success = false;
    }
    else
    {
        //Use OpenGL 2.1
        SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 2);
        SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 1);

        //Create window
        gWindow = SDL_CreateWindow("SDL Tutorial", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
        if (gWindow == NULL)
        {
            printf("Window could not be created! SDL Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
            success = false;
        }
        else
        {
            //Create context
            gContext = SDL_GL_CreateContext(gWindow);
            if (gContext == NULL)
            {
                printf("OpenGL context could not be created! SDL Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
                success = false;
            }
            else
            {
                //Use Vsync
                if (SDL_GL_SetSwapInterval(1) < 0)
                {
                    printf("Warning: Unable to set VSync! SDL Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
                }

                //Initialize OpenGL
                if (!initGL())
                {
                    printf("Unable to initialize OpenGL!\n");
                    success = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return success;
}
GLuint LoadTexture(char *filename)
{

    SDL_Surface *surface;
    GLuint textureid;
    int mode;

    surface = SDL_LoadBMP(filename);

    // Or if you don't use SDL_image you can use SDL_LoadBMP here instead:
    // surface = SDL_LoadBMP(filename);

    // could not load filename
    if (!surface)
    {

        return 0;

    }

    // create one texture name
    glGenTextures(1, &textureid);

    // tell opengl to use the generated texture name
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureid);

    // this reads from the sdl surface and puts it into an opengl texture
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, surface->w, surface->h, 0, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, surface->pixels);

    // these affect how this texture is drawn later on...
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    // clean up
    SDL_FreeSurface(surface);
    //surface->w=dlugosc obrazka
    return textureid;

}


void resize(int width, int height)
{

    const float ar = (float)width / (float)height; //The width-to-height ratio
                                                   //Tell OpenGL how to convert from coordinates to pixel values
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height); //specifies the part of the window to which OpenGL will draw(in pixels), convert from normalised to pixels
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); //Switch to setting the camera perspective
                                 //Set the camera perspective
    glLoadIdentity();//Reset the camera
    glFrustum(-ar, ar, -1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 100.0);
    if (perspective_checker)
    {
        gluLookAt(0, 2, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);//widok standardowy-początkowy
    }
    else
    {
        gluLookAt(1.5, 4.7, 1.5, 1.5, 0, 1.5, 0, 0, -1);//widok "z góry"
    }
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    SDL_GetWindowSize(gWindow, &current_window_width, &current_window_height);

}

void handleKeys(SDL_Event &event)
{
    switch (event.key.keysym.sym)//get what key was pressed
    {

    case SDLK_d:
        if (perspective_checker)
        {
            //kostka.move(0.1, 0, 0);
            //obj.move(0.1, 0, 0);
        }
        break;
    case SDLK_a:
        if (perspective_checker)
        {
            //kostka.move(-0.1, 0, 0);
            //obj.move(-0.1, 0, 0);
        }
        break;
    case SDLK_q:
        perspective_checker = !perspective_checker;
        resize(current_window_width, current_window_height);
        break;
    }
}

void RysujTlo()
{

    // tell opengl to use the generated texture name
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tlo);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    //Render quad
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(-4.5, 2.65, 0.0);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0);
    glVertex3f(-6.0, -3.65, 0.0);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0);
    glVertex3f(9.5, -3.65, 0.0);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(4.5, 2.65, 0.0);
    glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}

bool initGL()
{

    bool success = true;
    GLenum error = GL_NO_ERROR;

    //Initialize Projection Matrix
    const float ar = (float)SCREEN_WIDTH / (float)SCREEN_HEIGHT; //The width-to-height ratio
                                                                 //Tell OpenGL how to convert from coordinates to pixel values
    glViewport(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT); //specifies the part of the window to which OpenGL will draw(in pixels), convert from normalised to pixels
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); //Switch to setting the camera perspective
                                 //Set the camera perspective
    glLoadIdentity();//Reset the camera
    glFrustum(-ar, ar, -1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 100.0);

    gluLookAt(0, 2, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0); //pierwsze 3 wpsolrzedne to polozenie kamery,nastepne 3 to punkt na jaki patrzy kamera, nastepne 3 to kierunek gory kamery
                                          //wektor [0,0,-1] o początku w punkcie (0,2,5), skierowany do tablicy,do monitora(dokładnie na punkt (0,0,0))
                                          //gluLookAt(1.5, 4.7, 1.5, 1.5, 0, 1.5, 0, 0, -1); save best1
                                          //gluLookAt(0, 3, 1.5, 0, 0, 1.5, 0, 0, -1);  save best2

                                          // /* Enable Z depth testing so objects closest to the viewpoint are in front of objects further away */
                                          //enable depth - test to remove the hidden surface, and set the function used for the depth test.

    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);

    //setLight();
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);

    //glHint
    //glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);
    /*In graphics rendering, there is often a trade - off between processing speed and visual quality.We can use glHint() to decide on the trade - off.
    In this case, we ask for the best perspective correction, which may involve more processing.The default is GL_DONT_CARE.*/

    //Check for error
    error = glGetError();
    if (error != GL_NO_ERROR)
    {
        printf("Error initializing OpenGL! %s\n", gluErrorString(error));
        success = false;
    }

    //Initialize Modelview Matrix
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    //Check for error
    error = glGetError();
    if (error != GL_NO_ERROR)
    {
        printf("Error initializing OpenGL! %s\n", gluErrorString(error));
        success = false;
    }

    //Initialize clear color
    glClearColor(0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 0.f);
    //Check for error
    error = glGetError();
    if (error != GL_NO_ERROR)
    {
        printf("Error initializing OpenGL! %s\n", gluErrorString(error));
        success = false;
    }
    return success;
}

void handleKeys(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    //Toggle quad
    if (key == 'q')
    {
        gRenderQuad = !gRenderQuad;
    }

}

void update()
{
    //No per frame update needed
}

void render()
{
    //Clear color buffer

    //kostka.drawCube();
        //kostka_2.drawCube();


}


void setObjectPosition()
{
    tlo = LoadTexture("background_front.bmp");
    //kostka.setPosition(0, 0.3, 3.0);
    //kostka_2.setPosition(3.2, 1.9, 0.5);

}

void close()
{
    //Destroy window    
    SDL_DestroyWindow(gWindow);
    gWindow = NULL;

    //Quit SDL subsystems
    SDL_Quit();
}

int main(int argc, char* args[])
{
    //Start up SDL and create window
    if (!init())
    {
        printf("Failed to initialize!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        //Main loop flag
        bool quit = false;

        //Event handler
        SDL_Event e;
        setObjectPosition();
        //Enable text input
        SDL_StartTextInput();

        //While application is running
        while (!quit)
        {
            //Handle events on queue
            while (SDL_PollEvent(&e) != 0)
            {
                //User requests quit
                if (e.type == SDL_QUIT)
                {
                    quit = true;
                }

                //Handle keypress with current mouse position
                else if (e.type == SDL_TEXTINPUT)
                {
                    int x = 0, y = 0;
                    SDL_GetMouseState(&x, &y);
                    handleKeys(e.text.text[0], x, y);
                }
                else if (e.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
                {
                    //Select surfaces based on key press 
                    handleKeys(e);
                    switch (e.key.keysym.sym)
                    {
                    case SDLK_ESCAPE:
                        quit = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            //Render quad
            RysujTlo();
            kostka.drawCube();
            //render();
            //Update screen
            SDL_GL_SwapWindow(gWindow);
        }

        //Disable text input
        SDL_StopTextInput();
    }

    //Free resources and close SDL
    close();

    return 0;
}
```

TesterClass_Cubic.cpp

```
#include "TesterClass_Cubic.h"
#include <SDL_opengl.h>



TesterClass_Cubic::TesterClass_Cubic()
{
}


TesterClass_Cubic::~TesterClass_Cubic()
{
}

TesterClass_Cubic::TesterClass_Cubic(double height, double red, double green, double blue) : m_height(height), m_r(red), m_g(green), m_b(blue)
{
    m_x = 0.0;
    m_y = 0.0;
    m_z = 0.0;
    m_angle = 0.0;
    m_hide = true;
}

void TesterClass_Cubic::motion()
{
    m_angle += 0.5;
    if (m_angle > 360)
        m_angle -= 360;
}
void TesterClass_Cubic::move(double dx, double dy, double dz)
{
    m_x += dx;
    m_y += dy;
    m_z += dz;
}

void TesterClass_Cubic::setPosition(double x, double y, double z)
{
    m_x = x;
    m_y = y;
    m_z = z;
}

void TesterClass_Cubic::drawCube()
{
    if (m_hide)
    {
        glPushMatrix();
            // angle, x-axis, y-axis, z-axis
                                                 // Render a color-cube consisting of 6 quads with different colors
                        // Reset the model-view matrix
            glTranslated(m_x, m_y, m_z);
            glRotated(m_angle, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);    // Move right and into the screen

            glBegin(GL_QUADS);                // Begin drawing the color cube with 6 quads
                                              // Top face (y = 1.0f)
                                              // Define vertices in counter-clockwise (CCW) order with normal pointing out
            glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);     // Green
            glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
            glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
            glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
            glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

            // Bottom face (y = -1.0f)
            //glColor3f(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f);     // Orange
            glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
            glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
            glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
            glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);

            // Front face  (z = 1.0f)
            //glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);     // Red
            glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
            glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
            glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
            glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);

            // Back face (z = -1.0f)
            //glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);     // Yellow
            glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
            glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
            glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
            glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);

            // Left face (x = -1.0f)
            //glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);     // Blue
            glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
            glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
            glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
            glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);

            // Right face (x = 1.0f)
            //glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);     // Magenta
            glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
            glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
            glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
            glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
            glEnd();  // End of drawing color-cube
        glPopMatrix();
    }
}
```

TesterClass_Cubic.h

```
#pragma once
class TesterClass_Cubic
{

private:
    double m_width;
    double m_height;
    double m_x;
    double m_y;
    double m_z;
    double m_angle;
    double m_r;
    double m_g;
    double m_b;
    bool m_hide;

public:
    TesterClass_Cubic();
    ~TesterClass_Cubic();
    TesterClass_Cubic(double height, double red, double green, double blue);
    void drawCube();
    void setPosition(double x, double y, double z);
    void move(double dx, double dy, double dz);
    void motion();

};
```

Im sorry for pasting the full code but Im not experienced user and not sure what do You need to help me.
What should I change in my code?
[Here is what do i see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8azQx.png)

[And here,how should the background look:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEpnV.png)

Comment: After the first glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); , all vertices will be set to draw in that color until another glColor3f is issued. Are you saying that if you un-comment out the other glColor3f's that those vertices are not drawing in the color set above it?

Comment: Thanks for this knowledge, I didn't know! When i un-comment out the other glColor3f's then the background texture colour is probably mix of all of the glColor3f's and it is my problem.

Comment: I uploaded screenshot maybe it will make my problem clearer for You

Comment: *What I notice* You don't have a glPushMatrix in the RysujTlo function but are calling glPopMatrix at the end of it. *I'll play with the code more when I have time*

Comment: Im trying a lot of different things and i pasted code in testing time, sorry. It does't help